# setState(...): This usually means you called set state() on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

## React , `setState(...)`:, called `setState()` on an `unmounted` component ???

### setState(...): This usually means you called set state() on an unmounted component.

> Warning: 
>   setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. 
>   This usually means you called set state() on an unmounted component.
>   This is a no-op. Please check the code for the TestModal component.

### I just can't figure out, what's wrong with this?

```jsx

```
class TestModal extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            loading: false,
            visible: true
        };
    }
    onTest = () => {
        // copy state, do test fetch
        this.testOK();
    };
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.form.validateFields(
            (err, values) => {
                if (!err) {
                    console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
                    console.log('fetch url = \n', values.textarea);
                    // fetch data
                    let url = values.textarea;
                    this.props.checkTestCommands(url);
                    this.onTest();
                }else{
                    throw new Error(Error.name, Error.message);
                }
            }
        );
    };
    testOK = () => {
        this.setState({
            loading: true
        });
        this.props.hideModal();
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
                loading: false,
                visible: false
            });
        }, 1000);
    }
    testCancel = () => {
        this.setState({
            visible: false
        });
        this.props.hideModal();
    }
    render() {
        const {getFieldsValue, getFieldValue, setFieldsValue, getFieldDecorator} = this.props.form;
        const formItemLayout = {
            labelCol: {
                span: 6
            },
            wrapperCol: {
                span: 14
            }
        };
        return (
            <div>
                {/* query object */}
                {/* no footer */}
                <Modal 
                    title="命令行"
                    onOk={this.testOK}
                    onCancel={this.testCancel}
                    visible={this.state.visible}
                    footer={[]}
                    >
                    {/* loading={this.state.loading} */}
                    <Form 
                        onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                        layout="horizontal">
                        <FormItem
                            label="测试命令行"
                            hasFeedback
                            {...formItemLayout}>
                            {
                                getFieldDecorator('textarea', {
                                    rules: [
                                        {
                                            required: false,
                                            message: ' url 长度必须 30 个字符之间'
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    initialValue: `http://10.1.5.31:8080/http/report/query?{"ApiName":"JY.Topic.Market_profile.Investors_data_statistics.AccountStatistics"}`,
                                })(
                                    <Input
                                        type="textarea"
                                        placeholder="请先点击 “开始测试” 按钮!"
                                        rows="10"
                                        cols="70"
                                        />
                                )
                            }
                        </FormItem>
                        {/* onClick={this.props.checkTestCommands} */}
                        <FormItem style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
                            <Button 
                                onClick={this.onTest}
                                type="primary"
                                htmlType="submit"
                                icon="hourglass"
                                style={{margin: "auto 10px"}}
                                loading={this.state.loading}>
                                开始测试
                            </Button>
                            <Button 
                                onClick={this.testCancel}
                                size="large"
                                style={{margin: "auto 10px"}}
                                icon="close">
                                关闭
                            </Button>
                            {/* ref="submit_btn" */}
                        </FormItem>
                    </Form>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

```

### this is a new version code, but it still doesn't work?

```js
class TestModal extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            loading: false,
            visible: true
        };
    }
    onTest = () => {
        // copy state, do test fetch
        this.testOK();
    };
/*     componentWillUnmount(){
        this.props.hideModal();
        this.setState({
            loading: false,
            visible: false
        });
    } */
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.form.validateFields(
            (err, values) => {
                if (!err) {
                    console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
                    console.log('fetch url = \n', values.textarea);
                    // fetch data
                    let url = values.textarea;
                    this.props.checkTestCommands(url);
                    this.onTest();
                }else{
                    throw new Error(Error.name, Error.message);
                }
            }
        );
    };
    testOK = () => {
        this.setState({
            loading: true
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
                loading: false,
                visible: false
            });
            this.props.hideModal();
        }, 1000);
    }
    testCancel = () => {
        this.setState({
            visible: false
        });
        this.props.hideModal();
    }
    render() {
        const {getFieldsValue, getFieldValue, setFieldsValue, getFieldDecorator} = this.props.form;
        const formItemLayout = {
            labelCol: {
                span: 6
            },
            wrapperCol: {
                span: 14
            }
        };
        return (
            <div>
                {/* query object */}
                {/* no footer */}
                <Modal 
                    title="命令行"
                    onOk={this.testOK}
                    onCancel={this.testCancel}
                    visible={this.state.visible}
                    footer={[]}
                    >
                    {/* loading={this.state.loading} */}
                    <Form 
                        onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                        layout="horizontal">
                        <FormItem
                            label="测试命令行"
                            hasFeedback
                            {...formItemLayout}>
                            {
                                getFieldDecorator('textarea', {
                                    rules: [
                                        {
                                            required: false,
                                            message: ' url 长度必须 30 个字符之间'
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    initialValue: `http://10.1.5.31:8080/http/report/query?{"ApiName":"JY.Topic.Market_profile.Investors_data_statistics.AccountStatistics"}`,
                                })(
                                    <Input
                                        type="textarea"
                                        placeholder="请先点击 “开始测试” 按钮!"
                                        rows="15"
                                        cols="500"
                                        />
                                )
                            }
                        </FormItem>
                        {/* onClick={this.props.checkTestCommands} */}
                        <FormItem style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
                            <Button 
                                onClick={this.onTest}
                                type="primary"
                                htmlType="submit"
                                icon="hourglass"
                                style={{margin: "auto 10px"}}
                                loading={this.state.loading}>
                                开始测试
                            </Button>
                            <Button 
                                onClick={this.testCancel}
                                size="large"
                                style={{margin: "auto 10px"}}
                                icon="close">
                                关闭
                            </Button>
                            {/* ref="submit_btn" */}
                        </FormItem>
                    </Form>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

## a screencut gif!

[image]

Comment: Is there a line referenced?

Comment: @ Nocebo sorry, for that! I just run it on my local server using PC!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `testOK` method you are calling `setState` after 1sec delay when the TestModal form is already closed (that is the component is already unmounted). This is a noop.

Comment: Make sure that `hideModal` is allways called last. Especially if you use `setState` that is async. Use its second argument to provide callback function where you will hide modal after `setState` has finished

Comment: well, you know I'm a newbie of react, can you show me a simple demo, thanks in advance?

Comment: Sure. This is the right place in docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate. And your code will look similar to:  `this.setState({...}, () => { /* Do things after setState is completed here */})`

Comment: Thanks for your kind help!

Comment: after I fixed it tomorrow, I will accept your answer!

Answer (score 1):

this is where you have the problem

```
this.props.hideModal();

setTimeout(() => 
{
     this.setState({
          loading: false,
          visible: false
          });
}, 1000);
```

you hide the modal and after 1 second you try to change the state

Answer (score 0):

## here is one of my solutions!

> Hooray, it works now! Just need to remove the duplicate set `visible=false`, it should be always `visible=true`;
>   because it should be call parent component's methods to realize `show/hide` itself!

### Thanks to everybody, who made his answer to this question!

```jsx

```
class TestModal extends Component {
constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
        loading: false,
        visible: true
    };
}
onTest = () => {
    // copy state, do test fetch
    this.testOK(); 
};
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields(
        (err, values) => {
            if (!err) {
                console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
                console.log('fetch url = \n', values.textarea);
                // fetch data
                let url = values.textarea;
                this.props.checkTestCommands(url);
                // this.onTest();
            }else{
                throw new Error(Error.name, Error.message);
            }
        }
    );
};
testOK = (e) => {
    // e.preventDefault();
    console.log(`testOK e`, e);
    this.setState({
        loading: true
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
            loading: false
        });
        this.props.hideModal();
    }, 1000);
}
testCancel = () => {
   this.props.hideModal();
}
render() {
    const {getFieldsValue, getFieldValue, setFieldsValue, getFieldDecorator} = this.props.form;
    const formItemLayout = {
        labelCol: {
            span: 6
        },
        wrapperCol: {
            span: 14
        }
    };
    // destructuring assignment
    const {visible, loading} = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            {/* query object */}
            {/* no footer */}
            <Modal 
                title="命令行"
                onOk={this.testOK}
                onCancel={this.testCancel}
                visible={visible}
                footer={[]}
                >
                {/* loading={this.state.loading} */}
                <Form 
                    onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                    layout="horizontal">
                    <FormItem
                        label="测试命令行"
                        hasFeedback
                        {...formItemLayout}>
                        {
                            getFieldDecorator('textarea', {
                                rules: [
                                    {
                                        required: false,
                                        message: ' url 长度必须 30 个字符之间'
                                    }
                                ],
                                initialValue: `10.1.5.31:8080/http/report/query?{"SecuCode":"000011","Names":"阳琨","ApiName":"fund.f9.fund_profile.FundManager.BasicInformations","WriteType":"json"}`,
                            })(
                                <Input
                                    type="textarea"
                                    placeholder="请先点击 “开始测试” 按钮!"
                                    rows="15"
                                    cols="500"
                                    />
                            )
                        }
                    </FormItem>
                    {/* onClick={this.props.checkTestCommands} */}
                    <FormItem style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
                        <Button 
                            onClick={this.onTest}
                            type="primary"
                            htmlType="submit"
                            icon="hourglass"
                            style={{margin: "auto 10px"}}
                            loading={loading}>
                            开始测试
                        </Button>
                        <Button 
                            onClick={this.testCancel}
                            size="large"
                            style={{margin: "auto 10px"}}
                            icon="close">
                            关闭
                        </Button>
                        {/* ref="submit_btn" */}
                    </FormItem>
                </Form>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

```